# Can't add jquery ui tooltip to view in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, tooltip

All,

I'm new to Backbone.js and I'm struggling with adding jQuery UI tooltip behavior to HTML elements from within a Backbone.js view, and I'm wondering if you can help.

In my `render()` function, I have some code that attempts to add a tooltip like this:

```
render: function() 
{
  …other code here…

this.$el.find(".test").tooltip(
{
  content: "<h1>dude!</h1>"
});
return this;
},
```

However the tooltip content does not get correctly associated with the HTML elements…resulting in no tooltip popup. No console errors, but no popup. On the other hand, simple things like the following that do not use a jQuery UI plugin work just fine:

```
this.$el.find(".test").css("background", "red");
```

I'm pretty sure I'm adding the tooltip correctly; I have a working jsFiddle of what I'm trying to do here (without Backbone.js): http://jsfiddle.net/Mkk4w/. If you hover over one of the images you will get a tooltip pop-up.

Other articles on StackOverflow and Google suggest the "in-memory DOM" constructed by Backbone `(this.$el)` is not complete enough to use in the `render()` function, which is causing the jQuery UI tooltip function to not be bound correctly. They say this code should not be in the `render()` function but should be elsewhere in the Backbone app. I've tried many variations on these other approaches, but I'm not having any luck. I'm pretty sure this is some kind of incomplete/wrong context issue but I can't figure it out.

I sure would appreciate any thoughts you have on how to get this to work.

Comment: The "in-memory DOM" problem occurs when you try to bind something that needs to know the position and size of the element it is binding to, a Google Map for example. The size and position aren't generally available until the elements have been placed on the page and rendered. The answer below suggests that this isn't a problem for your tooltip plugin, it probably queries the position and size when it reacts to a hover.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/9cvVv/613/) showing a Backbone.View rendering a jQuery UI tooltip. Here is the javascript:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#a-tpl').html()),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.append(this.template());  
        this.$el.find('.test').tooltip({
            content: "<h1>Dude!</h1>"
        })
        return this; 
    }
});

var view = new View({});
$('body').append(view.render().el);
```

And the corresponding html template

```
<script type="text/tpl" id="a-tpl">
    <a class="test" title="" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    </a>
</script>
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the code I have (that isn't working). However, the real application code is adding the anchor link elements with .test class dynamically in Javascript, like this: 
var html = {a bunch of stuff being constructed}
this.$el.find("#sections").append(html);
So they don't already exist in the DOM. Does this change your answer?

Comment: what about adding the tooltip in a dynamically created element...your code is for HTML already exisitng in the DOM